# Nothing entered into database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm writing a python-program that is supposed to enter some data into a database. This does not work. Here's the code:

```
dbcon = lite.connect('spcbase.db')  # Connects to database file spcbase.db.
    print "Connected to database"
    cur=dbcon.cursor()                  # Creates database cursor.
    print "Cursor defined"
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spectrum(spectrumID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, seriesID INTEGER, scan_ang DECIMAL, Path TEXT)")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS series(seriesID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date DATE, gpsx DECIMAL, gpsy DECIMAL, colprec DECIMAL, refangle DECIMAL)")
        # Executes SQL-query that will create one table of spectrums
        # and one table over series of measurements, should these
        # tables or this database not exist.
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO series(date, gpsx, gpsy, colprec, refangle) VALUES(CURRENT_DATE, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [AP[0], AP[1], 6, refangle])
    dbcon.commit()
    cur.execute("SELECT MAX(seriesID) FROM series")
    dbcon.commit()
    current_series = cur.fetchone()[0]
    src = u'.\\MaestroData'
    print src
    dest = u'.\\target'
    print dest
    files=getspc(src)
    i=0
    for mfile in files:
        oldpath=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(src,mfile))
        print "oldpath: ", oldpath
        newpath=os.path.normpath(os.path.join(dest,mfile))
        print "newpath", newpath
        try:
           os.rename(oldpath,newpath)
        except:
            print "File not moved."
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO spectrum(seriesID, scan_ang, Path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [current_series, scan_dirs[i], newpath])
        dbcon.commit()
        i=i+1
```

(This is not the entire program, only the database handling part.) When this is run a file called spcbase.db is created. It has size 0 and contains nothing. Where does it go wrong?

Comment: what is the output of the program when it runs? (There are some debug messages here which can help to find out if your program is trying to write anything).

Comment: There are no error messages, and the program ends neatly. Whatever output there is comes from the various print statements.

Comment: Have you tried to connect and insert data from the interactive prompt ? Have you tried to look at the contents (I use sqliteman) - are the tables being created for instance ? I have to say, from the code snippet you have posted - there is nothing obviously wrong with at first inspection.

Comment: I've come to realize that the problem is as trivial as me not entering the correct path.

Still - What is the 'interactive prompt' in this context?